# arraylist list not being recognized in another class

Tags: java, list, intellij-idea, minecraft, bukkit

I was creating a plugin to MineCraft which needs a list of `UUID` and I figured to do it this way

```
public class Freeze extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor {
    public static List<UUID> toggleList = new ArrayList<UUID>();
}
```

However when I'm using the list in another class it says `cannot resolve symbol`.
Here is the class for using the list not creating it

```
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;

public class Toggle implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent evt) {
        Player player = evt.getPlayer();
        if (Freeze.togglelist.contains(player.getUniqueId())){
            Location back = new Location(evt.getFrom().getWorld(), evt.getFrom().getX(), evt.getFrom().getY(), evt.getFrom().getZ());
            evt.getPlayer().teleport(back);
        }
    }
}
```

how can i get it to recognize it as the list?

Comment: You are not importing the class `Freeze`

Comment: Do a static import for the togglelist

Comment: Please read error messages. You do not get simply "cannot resolve symbol", you get a short message explaining what exactly was not resolved (or this is clear from context, i.e. the underlined token). If, as in this case, `Freeze` was not found, the obvious solution is to import it.

Answer (score 0):

## Static import

Add a [static import](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import) statement to your `Toggle` class.

```
import static my.package.Freeze ;
```

Or change your line of code to use the [fully-qualified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) name.

```
if ( my.package.Freeze.togglelist.contains( player.getUniqueId() ) ) {
```

And if working with retrieved [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) objects, you will need to import [that class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) as well.

```
import java.util.List ;
import java.util.UUID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

## No Static Import Required

The reason why your IDE is barking an error is because of a typo. You define `toggleList` in `Freeze`, but attempt to reference it with `Freeze.togglelist` (note that "list" is spelled with a lowercase 'l').

If your classes are in the same package, no further `import` directives are required. However, if `Freeze` is in a different package, a regular `import` (i.e., non-static) of `Freeze` is required, which is something your IDE should be able to resolve easily.

Comment: You might have forgot to import `Freeze.class`